# Solve Cubic Equation with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I need some help for solving a cubic equation. 
In this thread there is a solution of how a cubic equation can be solved with Mathematica

[The exact real solutions of a cubic polynomial?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109951/the-exact-real-solutions-of-a-cubic-polynomial)

I tried this solution but I don't get any output.

Only `th` is a variable. The rest are constants.

```
roots = Solve[
     s2 + 
       1/(96 jmax^2 (b1 - b2 + jmax tf)) (b1^4 + b2^4 - 
          b2^3 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
          b1^3 (-4 b2 + 4 jmax tf + 3 jmax th) + 
          3 b2^2 jmax^2 (2 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2) + 
          3 b1^2 (2 b2^2 - b2 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
             jmax^2 (2 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2)) + 
          3 b2 jmax^2 (32 s1 + 
             jmax (4 tf^3 - 3 tf^2 th - 2 tf th^2 + th^3) + 
             32 tf v1) - 
          b1 (4 b2^3 - 3 b2^2 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
             6 b2 jmax^2 (-6 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2) + 
             3 jmax^2 (32 s1 + 
                jmax (4 tf^3 - 3 tf^2 th - 2 tf th^2 + th^3) + 
                32 tf v2)) - 
          3 jmax^2 (jmax^2 tf (tf - th)^2 (tf + th) - 
             16 (v1 - v2)^2 + 16 jmax tf (2 s1 + tf (v1 + v2)))) == 0
     , th
     , Reals
     ] // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
```

Hope that somebody can help me 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What exactly is your question though? The `Solve` expression works and returns results as conditional expressions containing `Root` objects. The rest might take a very long time to execute, but do you need the `ToRadicals` etc? What do you need to do with the results?

Comment: @MarcoB As Result i want an exact Solution. If i just use Solve i get  3 Solutions for th. These 3 Solutions are really long--> it seems that its an approximation... So i found this Solve Command with Roots. I ran this command but now its running for 20 min ... and i don't think that i will get an solution.... I need the Exact Solution to use it in another Matlab skript to calculate this variable th for different constants... Hope that you understand what i mean

Comment: The `Root` object result is not an approximation.

Comment: @GiovanniCamodeca `Root` objects *are*, in fact, Mathematica's representation of *exact* solutions for higher order equations like yours. I'd suggest that you take those, plug in the numerical values of the constants, and calculate the corresponding values of `th` in Mathematica. Then export those to use wherever you need them.

Comment: ...Moreover any solution in terms of parametrized radicals will either require a conditional to switch between three values, or else will be incorrect for some values of the parameters (because when there is only one real valued solution, it need not always be in the same radical solution).

Comment: In fact, if ultimately what you want are numerical values of `th`, you might as well plug in the know values of your constants beforehand, and get a numerical solution of any arbitrary precision using `NSolve` rather than `Solve`. In short, **please edit your question to explain all these details** and include a few appropriate values of the constants so we can show you a sample solution.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the Help. @MarcoB When i am trying to get the roots as Solution i get an ConditionalExpression... and not an "equation" for th..... And i don't want to use NSolve  because ii don't want an approximation. And i can't insert values for the constants... because i don't know them yet. I only know that there are real.  because i have a Matlab Skript where the constants are calculated automatic... These Constants then should be inserted into the equation for th to get the Value th. That's why i need an exact solution. To be Honest i don't understand these roots and how to use them :/

Comment: …Then why not solve the equation numerically in _MATLAB_? Polynomial equation solving is a basic functionality, _MATLAB_ must have it built in.

Comment: Actually the Wolfram Language also has that built in (with multiple methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do the following.

First solve for the generic cubic in terms of radicals and then substitute.

```
subs=Thread[{a0, a1, a2, a3} -> 
   CoefficientList[
    s2 + 1/(96 jmax^2 (b1 - b2 + jmax tf)) (b1^4 + b2^4 - 
        b2^3 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
        b1^3 (-4 b2 + 4 jmax tf + 3 jmax th) + 
        3 b2^2 jmax^2 (2 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2) + 
        3 b1^2 (2 b2^2 - b2 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
           jmax^2 (2 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2)) + 
        3 b2 jmax^2 (32 s1 + 
           jmax (4 tf^3 - 3 tf^2 th - 2 tf th^2 + th^3) + 32 tf v1) - 
        b1 (4 b2^3 - 3 b2^2 jmax (4 tf + 3 th) + 
           6 b2 jmax^2 (-6 tf^2 + 3 tf th + th^2) + 
           3 jmax^2 (32 s1 + 
              jmax (4 tf^3 - 3 tf^2 th - 2 tf th^2 + th^3) + 
              32 tf v2)) - 
        3 jmax^2 (jmax^2 tf (tf - th)^2 (tf + th) - 16 (v1 - v2)^2 + 
           16 jmax tf (2 s1 + tf (v1 + v2)))), th] // FullSimplify]
  ToRadicals[Root[a3 #^3 + a2 #^2 + a1 # + a0 &, #]] & /@ {1, 2,3} /. subs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and Help :) Are the three Solutions which i get as output the 3 Solutions for th ?

Comment: Yes. And happy to help.

Comment: One Last Question: This Solution which you have generated is the same as the solution if you just use the solve command... only that the Equations are smaller is that right ?

Comment: @IlPad Yes. This is just a way to bypass too much of simplification that Mathematica would otherwise want to do if you had entered the complicated expression all at once.

Comment: Ok Thanks! and if i change the cubic function to an quadric i just have to add an a4 or ?

Comment: @IlPad Right. That will do.

Comment: Is it also possible to Solve an equation with 6th potenz with this method?