# How to obtain exact answers for casus irreducibilis for third order equation in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula
When a cubic equation with real coefficients has three real roots, the formulas expressing these roots in terms of radicals involve complex numbers. Galois theory allows proving that when the three roots are real, and none is rational (casus irreducibilis), one cannot express the roots in terms of real radicals. Nevertheless, purely real expressions of the solutions may be obtained using trigonometric functions, specifically in terms of cosines and arccosines, by Vieta's formulas.

Is it possible  to ask Mathematica to use this real representation, instead of radicals?

Comment: Check [this prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109951/the-exact-real-solutions-of-a-cubic-polynomial) or [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28683/unexpected-complex-roots-from-solving-a-cubic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = t^3 + p*t + q == 0;

solRad = Assuming[4 p^3 + 27 q^2 < 0,
  Solve[eqn, t] // ToRadicals // Simplify]

(* {{t -> (-2 3^(1/3) p + 2^(1/3) (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(2/3))/(
   6^(2/3) (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(1/3))}, 
   {t -> (2 2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) (3 I + Sqrt[3]) p + 
    I 2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) (I + Sqrt[3]) (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(2/3))/(
   12 (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(1/3))}, 
   {t -> (2 2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) (-3 I + Sqrt[3]) p + 
    2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(2/3))/(
   12 (-9 q + Sqrt[12 p^3 + 81 q^2])^(1/3))}}
```

Verifying the solution,

```
Assuming[4 p^3 + 27 q^2 < 0, eqn /. solRad // Simplify]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

To convert to trig expressions use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) with the option [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) set to `{Re, Im}`

```
solTrig = Assuming[4 p^3 + 27 q^2 < 0,
  solRad // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify]

(* {{t -> (2 Sqrt[-p] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-9 q, Sqrt[-12 p^3 - 81 q^2]]])/Sqrt[
   3]}, 
   {t -> -(1/3)
      Sqrt[-p] (Sqrt[3] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-9 q, Sqrt[-12 p^3 - 81 q^2]]] + 
      3 Sin[1/3 ArcTan[-9 q, Sqrt[-12 p^3 - 81 q^2]]])}, 
   {t -> -(1/3)
      Sqrt[-p] (Sqrt[3] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[-9 q, Sqrt[-12 p^3 - 81 q^2]]] - 
      3 Sin[1/3 ArcTan[-9 q, Sqrt[-12 p^3 - 81 q^2]]])}} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[t /. solTrig],
 {p, q} ∈ ImplicitRegion[4 p^3 + 27 q^2 < 0, {p, q}],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]